# Bootstrap Rails - Change background color, not working?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a Ruby on Rails site based off the RailsTutorial. I'm trying to change a few colors, but I can't figure it out.

I would like to change the background color [body of page] and the color of the menu text. Where can I do this?

my current custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
table td {
  padding:0px 25px 0px 0px;
}
table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding:0px 25px 0px 0px;
}



/* bootstrap */

.navbar-inner {
  background-color: white; /* background color will be black for all browsers */
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: none;
}


/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
p2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height:1.7em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
  }
}
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a lot of customization by default. You can find all the options here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just use sass variables instead of less.

```
$body-bg: #fff;

$navbar-default-color: #000;

$navbar-default-link-color: #000;
```

and so on… You will get what you want

Answer (score 1):

to change color of navbar

```
.navbar {
   background-color: red;
}
```

to change navbar nav links color

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. Text color worked, but background color of the body (not navbar) thanks

Comment: then why not just add css on body

Comment: body { background-color:red; }

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to be in scaffolds.css.scss instead of custom.css.scss. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
div.navbar{
background: red;
color:#fff
}
```

Change the colors to your needs.